# I'm writing a macro for ImageJ and I just need to overlay an oval over a triangle

Tags: imagej

This seems to only work for the fourth set of code, and all of these circles centers are the same and im not sure why. here is the code:

```
//Circumcircle

run("Specify...", "width="+(r1*2)+" height="+(r1*2)+" x1="+cenX1+" y1="+cenY1+" oval centered");
Overlay.addSelection("cyan");

run("Specify...", "width="+(r2*2)+" height="+(r2*2)+" x2="+cenX2+" y2="+cenY2+" oval centered");
Overlay.addSelection("yellow");

run("Specify...", "width="+(r3*2)+" height="+(r3*2)+" x3="+cenX3+" y3="+cenY3+" oval centered");
Overlay.addSelection("magenta");

run("Specify...", "width="+(r4*2)+" height="+(r4*2)+" x4="+cenX4+" y4="+cenY4+" oval centered");
Overlay.addSelection("red");// this is the only one that seems to be oriented correctly.
```

Comment: Are the other ones appearing? Can you include all of the necessary values to reproduce this. ie r1, cenX1, cenY1 ?

Comment: After trying it out, the issue seems to be `" x3="` why are you using x3? You should probably use `x` and same with the `y` value.

Comment: Oh wait, i didnt realize i changed those!! that was the issue, that helped! thank you so much!